# Собрать си программу без лишних секций под x64

Tags: c, visual-studio, компиляция, x86-64

В общем проблема такая: пытаюсь собрать си программу (из под native tools vs x64: cl prog.c) программа собирается с лишними секциями, от которых мне необходимо избавиться. (.reloc, .pdata). Аналогичную программу собираю под x32 та же самая проблема. Запустил vmware. Собрал там под x32 все хорошо, 3 секции, без тех, что я указал выше. Я бы собрал под x64 там же для проверки, но виртуалка 32-разрядная, по умолчанию командная строка собирает под 32р. Как собрать программу под x64 без лишних секций, как я это сделал для 32р в виртуалке и можно ли из под 32-разрядной виртуалки собрать программу под x64. Быть может с помощью ключа /platform. Секции смотрю в PE tools